# Уточнение, нужны здесь запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, уточнения

*В реальности «Спартак» выиграл большим для футбола счетом* – нужны здесь запятые и где?

*Одной из форм опыта, согласно Артемьевой являются манипуляции.* Нужна запятая после "Артемьевой"?

*На этой фазе впервые отчетливо проступают процессы абстракции*. "Впервые" в данном контексте выделяется запятыми?

Answer (score 1):

В первой фразе не вижу ни запятой, ни "уточнения". Предлога тоже не вижу. Если он случайно потерялся, то его надо восстановить ("**с** большим счетом"), но другого вмешательства не требуется.

Во второй интересующая запятая нужна, если вы настаиваете на обособлении "согласно Артемьевой". Оно здесь опционально. Я бы наоборот убрал запятую после "опыта".

В третьей фразе просто никаких причин для запятых не усматриваю.

Comment: Спасибо! понятно и доступно ответили!)) какое можно правило почитать касательно "согласно Артемьевой", чтобы отличать что является уточнением, а что нет?

Comment: Да какое тут "правило", говорю же - опционально. Если только это поможет восприятию текста. Интуитивно понятно, что причин для обособления "согласно" обычно нет.  А "теорию" можно посмотреть здесь http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_693 и здесь http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum_attach1/  Только вы там без подготовки утонете в формулировках,  оговорках и исключениях из оговорок.

Answer (score 0):

СОГЛАСНО, предлог и член предложения

1. Предлог. Обстоятельственные обороты «согласно + существительное» могут выделяться знаками препинания (запятыми). Подробнее о факторах, влияющих на расстановку знаков препинания, см. в Приложении 1.

Я несколько отодвинулся от стены и, согласно рыцарским правилам нашего базара, тоже положил руки в карманы. В. Короленко, В дурном обществе. Нос с по-зверушечьи чуткими ноздрями, темнеющий пушок над губой, вызывающе вздернутый подбородок со вмятинкой – все как бы рассеяно, разбросано и присутствовало на лице только потому, что согласно природе обязано здесь присутствовать. В. Астафьев, Обертон. «В другое время, nur nicht heute», – думал я согласно с известным немецким двустишием. И. Гончаров, Фрегат «Паллада».

Оборот с предлогом «согласно» не выделяется запятыми, если он является частью сказуемого или тесно связан со сказуемым по смыслу.

В комнате Коли вечер наступал согласно законам природы, поскольку свет там давно не горел. Л. Петрушевская, Козел Ваня.

2. Член предложения. Не требует постановки знаков препинания.

Самодовольствие и вместе некоторая неуверенность изображались на его лице; его праздничная наружность, его гордая походка заставили бы меня расхохотаться, если б это было согласно с моими намерениями. М. Лермонтов, Герой нашего времени. Да я готов всю жизнь босиком ходить, только бы жить всегда согласно с женой. Л. Толстой, Греческий учитель Сократ. Ни гука, ни стука сюда, за невидимую стену, не пробивалось, запустение приятно грело душу, навевало покой и окунало в сладкую и далеко уводящую задумчивость, в которой неслышно и согласно беседуют одни только души. В. Распутин, Изба.